# Conditional formatting: making cells colorful

Tags: excel, r, formatting

is it possible to do the following:

```
loc1 <- c("Aa", "Aa", "aa", "Aa")
loc2 <- c("aa", "aa", "aa", "AA")
loc3 <- c("aa", "Aa", "aa", "aa")
gen <- data.frame(loc1, loc2, loc3)

loc1g <- c(0.01, 0.5, 1, 0.75)
loc2g <- c(0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.6)
loc3g <- c(0.8, 0.8, 0.55, 1)
pval <- data.frame(loc1g, loc2g, loc3g)
```

I want to print to a file to gen dataframe such way that is conditionally formatted by the pval dataframe. Means than (row1, col1) of gen color depends upon pvale (row1, col1). The following are color coding:

```
0 to 0.3   is "red" text color 
0.31 to 0.7 is "yellow"
> 0.7  is "red"
```

gen[1,1] will be "Aa" printed in red text color and so on....

appreciated your help.

EDITS:

I am more interested in printing not plotting in graph. If I can save output as MS excel and open in MSEXCEL it would be great. I can also be other types of text editors format that can read color coded text. As my orginal data matrix should be of a dimension of 1000 x 1000 or even more. I would like to quicky know unlying p-value for each gen categories.

Comment: What kind of file did you have in mind?  One could do this as a graphic, a latex file, or Excel, to name just a few options.

Comment: And also to clarify, you can't do this in plain text, such as the output in an interactive R session. Plain text doesn't have colors...

Comment: You could generate the table in some kind of markdown language (see eg. `ascii` package), but be prepared: basic R console/GUI/IDE will not be able to parse/colorize that. HTML/LaTeX/xls might be another option.

Comment: thank you for help, please see my edits....I would appreciate it if you elaborate or provide codes for the purposed solution, sorry for my limited knowlege ...

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just use R to find out which p-values are 'unlying'. Even with color-coding a 1000 x 1000 matrix is a hell to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Giving a POC-like answer which is using an ugly loop and not the most beatiful design:

Loading eg. the `xlxs` package to be able to write to Excel 2007 format:

```
library(xlsx)
```

Let us create a workbook and a sheet (see the manual!):

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
sheet <- createSheet(wb, "demo")
```

Define some styles to use in the spreadsheet:

```
red <- createCellStyle(wb, fillBackgroundColor="tomato", fillForegroundColor="yellow", fillPattern="BIG_SPOTS")
yellow <- createCellStyle(wb, fillBackgroundColor="yellow", fillForegroundColor="tomato", fillPattern="BRICKS1")
```

And the ugly loop which is pasting each cell to the spreadsheet with appropriate format:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(pval)) {
    rows <- createRow(sheet, rowIndex=i)
    for (j in 1:ncol(pval)) {
        cell.1 <- createCell(rows, colIndex=j)[[1,1]]
        setCellValue(cell.1, gen[i,j])
        if ((pval[i,j] < 0.3) | (pval[i,j] > 0.7)) {
            setCellStyle(cell.1, red)
        } else {
            setCellStyle(cell.1, yellow)
        }
    }
}
```

Saving the Excel file:

```
saveWorkbook(wb, '/tmp/demo.xls')
```

Result: [demo.xls](http://www.2shared.com/document/vGa70w4S/demo.html)

---

Alternative solution with package `ascii`:

`ascii.data.frame()` can export data frames to a bunch of formats with the ability of adding some formatting. E.g. exporting to *pandoc*, first define the styles of each cells to an array with the same dimensions as `pval`:

```
style <- matrix('d', dim(pval)[1], dim(pval)[2])
style[pval < 0.3 | pval > 0.7] <- 's'
```

Set the desired output:

```
options(asciiType = "pandoc")
```

And export the data frame:

```
> ascii(gen, style=cbind('h', style))

    **loc1**   **loc2**   **loc3**  
--- ---------- ---------- ----------
1   Aa         **aa**     **aa**    
2   **Aa**     **aa**     Aa        
3   **aa**     aa         **aa**    
4   **Aa**     **AA**     **aa**    
--- ---------- ---------- ----------
```

With `ascii::Report` you could easily convert it it pdf, odt or html. Just try it :) Small demo with *HTML* output: [result](http://www.2shared.com/document/WNCxQzFA/tmp_RtmphTU9dc_R-report508af0b.html)

```
r <- Report$new()
r$add(section("Demo"))
r$add(ascii(gen, style=cbind('h', style)))
options(asciiType = "pandoc")
r$backend <- "pandoc"
r$format <- "html"
r$create()
```

And *odt* output: [result](http://www.2shared.com/file/aVRoCn9w/R-report3eb68ae8.html)

```
r$format <- "odt"
r$create()
```

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want to mimic Excel. Here are a couple examples:

```
x = 1:ncol(pval)
y = 1:nrow(pval)

# Colored backgrounds
dev.new(width=4, height=4)
image(x, y, t(as.matrix(pval)),
  col = c('red', 'yellow', 'red'),
  breaks = c(0, 0.3, 0.7, 1),
  xaxt='n', 
  yaxt='n', 
  ylim=c(max(y)+0.5, min(y)-0.5), 
  xlab='', 
  ylab='')
centers = expand.grid(y, x)
text(centers[,2], centers[,1], unlist(gen))
```

[image]

```
# Colored text
dev.new(width=4, height=4)
image(x,y, matrix(0, length(x), length(y)),
  col='white',
  xaxt='n', 
  yaxt='n', 
  ylim=c(max(y)+0.5, min(y)-0.5), 
  xlab='', 
  ylab='')
pvals = unlist(pval)
cols = rep('red', length(pvals))
cols[pvals>0.3 & pvals<=0.7] = 'yellow'
text(centers[,2], centers[,1], unlist(gen), col=cols)
grid(length(x),length(y))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, seems interesting to do it....can be partial solution if I want to see in part. Please see my recent edits to question, I am interested in more text based output printing rather in graphics...my imagination was to do something that we can do in excel, although I believe excel provide formatting on value on the cell itself not from other matrix.

Answer (score 2):

If you **really** want to do this (see @Joris's comment for a better way), I would strongly recommend ditching Excel and trying it in LaTeX.  Use the R package `xtable` combined with the [LaTeX package `\colortbl`](http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/tutorial/chap08-scr.pdf).

Advantages:

- Pretty printing
- No Excel hassles (exporting to Excel is easy; exporting to Excel while maintaining formatting is much harder, and a recipe for errors)

Disadvantages:

- It's not Excel
- It'll probably take some work to make the colors work with `xtable`.  However, you only have to do this once and then it will work forever--you can even release your function in a package or submit it to the xtable maintainers for inclusion in their package and save everyone else the trouble.